# Php, codeigniter, ajax, mysql

Tags: php

I want to update record in the database with ajax without reloading the page.

```
//Here is my controller.
Public function changeid()
{
  $this->view->('admin/change_id');
}

Public function ajax_changeid()
{
  $old_id =$_POST[studentid];
  $newid =$_POST[new_id];
  If(isset($_POST[`new_id')){
  $data =array(
         'student_id'=>trim($newid));
  $this->db->where('student_id', $old_id);
  $this->db->update('student');
  echo "info submited";
}
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**My view form change_id**

```
<form id='formajax' method='post' name='form'>
<input type="text" id="studentid"   
name="studentid"          readonly="readonly" 
value="<?   php echo $row-    >student_id; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="new_id" id="new_id"   >
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit"     
value="Update"     class="button success"   
onclick="myFunction()"  />
<\form>

//  Ajax script
<script>
//ajaxForm({
//function myFunction(){
(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnsubmit").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var stud_id =         
  document.getElementById("new_id").value;
  var studentid =      
  document.getElementById("studentid").value;
  var dataString = 'new_id1=' + new_id + 
  '$studentid1=' + studentid;

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url()?    
    >"+"index.php/school_settings/ajax_changeid",
    data:dataString,
    cache:false,
    success:function(html){
    //alert(html);
    alert('im working');

    }
  });
  return false;

  });
});
</script>
```

The challenge is the page keep reloading every time. 
i click submit button without doing anything. 
i want to be able to change id and get a success
message displayed without reloading d page.

Comment: what is your problem ? error ? question?

Comment: Is the above the actual code - there are errors in the php function `ajax_changeid`

Comment: fix this and chk the result <\form> into </form>

Comment: isset($_POST[`new_id') what is it

Comment: I just want to update the record inside database without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your code, use this modified code:

**Controller:**

```
public function changeid()
{
  $this->load->view('admin/change_id');
}

public function ajax_changeid()
{
  $old_id = $_POST['studentid'];
  $newid =$_POST['new_id'];
  if(isset($_POST['new_id']))
  {
    $data =array(
           'student_id'=>trim($newid));
    $this->db->where('student_id', $old_id);
    $this->db->update('student');
    echo "info submited";
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<form id='formajax' method='post' name='form'>
<input type="text" id="studentid" name="studentid" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row->student_id;?>"/>
<input type="text" name="new_id" id="new_id">
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Update" class="button success" onclick="myFunction()"/>
</form>
```

**What i have changed?**

- Change load view function as `$this->load->view('admin/change_id');` instead of `$this->view->('admin/change_id');`
- Change isset chekcing `` isset($_POST[`new_id') `` as `isset($_POST['new_id'])`, you have missed the ending ] bracket and also using backticks (Dont know why)
- Correct form ending tag `<\form>` as `</form>`
- Remove `onclick="myFunction()"` event from button, because you are using button id for onclick event in ajax.

Comment: It didn't work. When i clicked the button, nothing happened, i did not even get any alert

Comment: @user3805094: atleast debug your code... print_r($_POST); in your ajax_changeid()   function check getting values or not

Comment: I think the form and the controller are not seeing the ajax script which is on the same page with the view form